How to access update a variable in a azure pipeline?
In the code below the variable component is not getting updated to its new value by the line,
Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=component;isOutput=true]$(sdf)"
although the condition if ("$(Resources.TriggeringAlias)" -eq "abc" is true

# Define variables
variables:

    newrel: "0.1"
    component: ""

resources: 

    pipelines: 

     - pipeline: A_Pipeline 

       source: abc 

       project: pqr 

       trigger: 

       branches: 

       include: - '*' 

       - pipeline: B_Pipeline 

         source: xyz 

         project: pqr 

         trigger: 

           branches: 

             include: - '*'


jobs:
  - job: DetermineComponentDirectory
   
 
   displayName: "Determine Component Directory"
    
  steps:
       
        - checkout: none

        - powershell: 

            if ("$(Resources.TriggeringAlias)" -eq "abc") 

                 {
   
                   Write-Host "abc Pipeline in pqr succeeded"
                    Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=component;isOutput=true]$(sdf)"
                  }     ```


Is the answer below also helpful for you? @kiranitagi

Yes @Bright Ran-MSFT

The below line is to create an output variable that is different from the exiting pipeline variable, even if they have the same name.
Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=component;isOutput=true]$(sdf)"

If you just want to update the value of an existing pipeline variable, you should use the command like as below.
Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=component;]$(sdf)"

NOTE: The updated value only available for the subsequent tasks within current job.
If you want to also pass the updated value to the subsequent jobs/stages, you can keep set it as an output variable. To use output variable, you can reference the documentation "Use output variables from tasks".
